# Classes, Hidden Attributes and Inheritance

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, inheritance, attributes

I am pretty new to OOP and Python. Pretty much everything that I know is self-taught, so I would be grateful if you can provide just links for me to read since I do not know the exact terminology that I should seek in order to clarify my doubts.

This is my code so far:

```
class Point(object):
    x = 2
    y = 3

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x_a = x
        self.y_b = y

class RectPoint(Point):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x_1 = x
        self.y_1 = y
        self.dist = (x*x + y*y)**0.5


class CircPoint(Point):
    pass

a = Point(3,4)
b = CircPoint(3,4)
c = RectPoint(3,4)

print a.x     # 2
print a.y     # 3
print a.x_a   # 3
print a.y_b   # 4
print b.x     # 2
print b.y     # 3
print b.x_a   # 3
print b.y_b   # 4
print c.x     # 2
print c.y     # 3
print c.x_1   # 3
print c.y_1   # 4
print c.dist  # 5.0
print c.x_a   # AttributeError
print c.y_b   # AttributeError
```

Why are the attributes `self.x_a` and `self.y_b` not available for the class `RectPoint` but available for `CircPoint`? How would I make them available?

Further, why are the `self.x` and `self.y` available for the two classes `RectPoint` and `CircPoint`?

Links for further reading would also be appreciated (in place of an explanation)

Comment: I'll let more experienced users explain thoroughly; but in few words, `a` has everything it should have, obviously; `b` is a `CircPoint`, which inherits everything from `Point` and adds nothing, so it's got everything that `Point` has. On the other hand, `c` is a `RectPoint`, a class that inherits `x` and `y` from `Point` but where you define a different `__init__` method - so this overrides the method of the original class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `RectPoint.__init__` method *masks* the `Point.__init__` method. Because `Point.__init__` is not executed for `RectPoint` instances, the `self.x_a` and `self.y_b` attributes are never set. That's because Python searches first the instance, then the class, then the base classes for attributes. Methods are specialised attributes really, here. When creating an instance of a class, Python looks for the `__init__` method on the class, then on the base classes.

`CircPoint` does not implement their own `__init__` so the `Point.__init__` is found and used, and `self.x_a` and `self.y_b` *are* set.

You do specificy *class* attributes for `x` and `y`; Python finds these with the same search order; they are not set on the instance, and are eventually then found on the `Point` base class; either because you have a `Point` instance or a subclass of `Point` and the base classes of that subclass were searched.

You can *explicitly* call the overridden `__init__` method from `RectPoint.__init__`:

```
class RectPoint(Point):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super(RectPoint, self).__init__(x, y)
        self.x_1 = x
        self.y_1 = y
        self.dist = (x*x + y*y)**0.5
```

The [`super()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super) gives you access to the original `Point.__init__` method here, calling it first. That method then sets the `self.x_a` and `self.y_b` attributes, after which it'll return and the `RectPoint.__init__` method will set more attributes.

The [*Class* chapter of the Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) covers all this in some detail.

Comment: +1 I would just add (which I did in my own--abandoned--answer) that while in some languages `RectPoint` would implicitly call `Point`'s constructor, but Python is not one of those languages.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have a further question, not sure if I should plug it here or make it a separate one. Is there any practical application for variables that are not initialized in the `__init__` method? i.e. from my code the attributes `x` and `y`?

Comment: @M.Klugerford: yes, you can use those as defaults, or to share information between all instances. Compare this to architecture paper; you can layer the base classes, the class and the instance on top of one another and see the data through the layers, but *setting* an attribute on the instance will hide the attribute (mask) on the class. But you can always set the attribute *directly* on the class with `ClassObject.attribute_name = new_value`.

Answer (score 1):

`RectPoint` instances don't have `x_a` and `y_b` attributes because your `RectPoint.__init__` method never defines them, and never calls `Point.__init__` which would.

`x` and `y` are class attributes and are available on the class on which they are defined, any subclasses, and instances of those classes (unless overridden by setting the attribute on a subclass or instance). `self.x` looks for `x` first on the instance, and then if it's not found there, on the class and its parent classes.

Answer (score 1):

When you override **init** in a Python class you still need to call the **init** method of the class you inherited from or those attributes will not be available to your child class.  You do this with the super method.  In RectPoint, chang your **init** method like so:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.x_1 = x
    self.y_1 = y
    self.dist = (x*x + y*y)**0.5
    super(RectPoint,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
```